# Determinant of a certain Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinants

Compute the following determinant

\begin{vmatrix} x & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-1 & n\\ 1 & x & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1\\ 2 & 1 & x & 1 & \cdots & n-3 & n-2\\ 3 & 2 & 1 & x & \cdots & n-4 & n-3\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\ n-1 & n-2 & n-3 & n-4 & \cdots & x & 1\\ n & n-1 & n-2 & n-3 & \cdots & 1 &x \end{vmatrix}

I tried the following. I subtracted the second row from the first, the third from the second, the fourth from the third, and so on. I got:

\begin{vmatrix} 
x-1 & 1-x & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1\\
 -1 & x-1 & 1-x & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1\\ 
-1 & -1 & x-1 & 1-x & \cdots & 1 & 1\\ 
-1 & -1 & -1 & x-1 & \cdots & 1 & 1\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\ 
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots & x-1 & 1-x\\ 
n & n-1 & n-2 & n-3 & \cdots & 1 &x \end{vmatrix}

I did the same thing with the columns. I subtracted the second row from the first, the third from the second, the fourth from the third, and so on. And I got:

\begin{vmatrix} 
2x-2 & -x & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\ 
-x & 2x-2 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\
 0 & -x & 2x-2 & -x & \cdots & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & -x & 2x-2 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2x-2 & 1-x\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1-x &x \end{vmatrix}

I hope I didn’t make a mistake somewhere. With this part I don't know what to do next. I don't know if I'm doing it right. Thank you in advance !

Comment: One could use the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to reduce it to $xL-2I$, where $L$ is the [finite difference matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755113/what-are-eigenvalues-of-higher-order-finite-differences-matrices), possibly with [other boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_the_second_derivative). Since the eigenvalues of $L$ are known in closed form, it is possible to piece together a solution, but this does not look like an easy computation.

Answer (score 9):

Let $A_{n+1}$ denote the determinant of the $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix in the question. By Laplace expansion over the first row, we get:
$$A_{n+1} = (2x-2)A_n + xB_n + (-1)^nC_n,$$
where
$$B_n := \det \begin{bmatrix} 
-x & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\
 0 & 2x-2 & -x & \cdots & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & -x & 2x-2 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2x-2 & 1-x\\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1-x &x \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$C_n := \det\begin{bmatrix} 
-x & 2x-2 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & -x & 2x-2 & -x & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -x & 2x-2 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2x-2 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1-x \end{bmatrix}
$$
Expanding both $B_n$ and $C_n$ over the first column, we get
$$B_n = (-x) A_{n-1} + (-1)^{n+1}C_{n-1}$$
and
$$C_n = (-x)C_{n-1} + (-1)^{n+1} D_{n-1},$$
where
$D_n$ is the determinant of the following $n\times n$ Toeplitz [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant):
\begin{bmatrix} 
2x-2 & -x & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
-x & 2x-2 & -x & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
 0 & -x & 2x-2 & -x & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & -x & 2x-2 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2x-2 
\end{bmatrix}
It is expressed in terms of [Lucas sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) and its generating function as follows:
\begin{split}
D_n &= U_{n+1}(2x-2,x^2) \\
&= \frac{(x-1+\sqrt{1-2x})^{n+1}-(x-1-\sqrt{1-2x})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{1-2x}}\\
&=[z^n]\ \frac{1}{1-(2x-2)z+x^2z^2}.
\end{split}

Plugging the recurrence formula for $B_n$ into that for $A_{n+1}$, we get
$$(\star)\qquad A_{n+1} = (2x-2)A_n - x^2 A_{n-1} + (-1)^{n+1}xC_{n-1} + (-1)^n C_n.$$

We now have all ingredients to derive a closed-form expression for $A_n$.

---

Taking into account $C_1=1-x$, we unroll the recurrence for $C_n$ to get:
\begin{split}
C_n &= (-x)^{n-1}(1-x)+(-1)^{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x^{n-1-i} D_i \\
&= (-x)^n+(-1)^{n+1} [z^{n-1}]\ \frac{1}{(1-xz)(1-(2x-2)z+x^2z^2)}.
\end{split}
We will need the generating function:
\begin{split}
\mathcal{C}(z) &:= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} C_n z^{n-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-xz)(1-(2x-2)z+x^2z^2)} - \frac{x}{1-xz} \\
&= \frac{1-x+(2x-2)xz-x^3z^2}{(1-xz)(1-(2x-2)z+x^2z^2)}.
\end{split}

Define the generating function for $A_n$:
$$\mathcal{A}(z) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n z^n.$$

Now, let's multiply the recurrence $(\star)$ by $z^{n-1}$ and sum over $n\geq 2$ to obtain:
$$\frac{\mathcal{A}(z) - A_1z - A_2z^2}{z^2} = (2x-2)\frac{\mathcal{A}(z) - A_1z}z - x^2\mathcal{A}(z) - xz\mathcal{C}(z) - (\mathcal{C}(z)-C_1),$$
implying that
$$\mathcal{A}(z) = \frac{z(x^5z^4-4x^4z^3+4x^3z^3+6x^3z^2-8x^2z^2-4x^2z+3xz^2+4xz+x-z)}{(1-xz)(1-(2x-2)z+x^2z^2)^2}$$
and thus
\begin{split}
A_n &= \frac12 D_n + \frac{n+1-x}2 D_{n-1} + \frac{x^n}2 \\
&=
\frac{(n+\sqrt{1-2x})(x-1+\sqrt{1-2x})^n-(n-\sqrt{1-2x})(x-1-\sqrt{1-2x})^n}{4\sqrt{1-2x}} + \frac{x^n}2.
\end{split}

---

**UPDATE.** Another way to proceed from the recurrences for $A_n$, $B_n$, $C_n$, and $D_n$ is to combine them into a single matrix recurrence:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} A_{n+1}\\ B_{n+1}\\ (-1)^{n+1}C_{n+1}\\ D_{n+1} \\ D_n\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 
2x-2 & x & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-x & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & x & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2x-2 & -x^2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix} A_{n}\\ B_{n}\\ (-1)^{n}C_{n}\\ D_{n} \\ D_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
From the characteristic polynomial of the matrix in r.h.s., we get a recurrence for $A_n$:
$$A_n = (5x - 4)A_{n-1} + (-10x^2 + 12x - 4)A_{n-2} + (10x^3 - 12x^2 + 4x)A_{n-3} + (-5x^4 + 4x^3)A_{n-4} + x^5A_{n-5},$$
from which it is easy to obtain an explicit formula.

---

**PS.** Up to the change of $x$ to $-x$, $A_n$ represents the characteristic polynomial of the distance matrix, also known as the [distance polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistancePolynomial.html), of the path graph $P_n$. Another formula (in terms of Chebyshev polynomials) for it is given in [OEIS A203993](https://oeis.org/A203993).